# Creating crosstab() pivot table in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.0

I have a rather complicated issue for myself which I hope someone can help me with.

I want to use PostgreSQL to enable me to create pivot tables from a geometry-less table.

To keep it simple I will just show the table structure i want to use for the pivot and then use the methods given to create others, I hope :)

The fields I want to use are `postcode_nospace_`, and `ageband`.

`ageband` will be the columns across the top with `postcode_nospace_` being the rows with a count of each postcode being the data.

There are 2132 records and of which some have more than one postcode, hence the count.

```
CREATE TABLE adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc
(
  ogc_fid integer NOT NULL,
  sort numeric(5,0),
  ageband character(12),
  postcode_nospace_ character(8),
  wkb_geometry geometry,
  CONSTRAINT activities_in_localities_asc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ogc_fid)
);
```

UPDATE:

Here is the outcome I want to achieve as shown in an excel pivot table with the same data.

```
postcode 18_24  25_34   35_44   45_54   55_64   65_74   Total Count
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BB115DE     1           2                   2      3       8
FY38LZ                              1       1              2
```

From looking around I have compiled the following SQL query. It groups by postcode and creates the field names required. However the fields are blank. I would ideally also want a `total_count` column at the end of the table.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT postcode_nospace_, ageband, count(ageband) as total_count
     FROM adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc
     GROUP BY postcode_nospace_, ageband
     ORDER BY postcode_nospace_'

     ,$$VALUES ('18-24'::text), ('25-34'), ('35-44'), ('45-54'), ('55-64'), ('65-74'), ('75-84'), ('85-94'), ('95 AND OVER')$$)
AS ct("postcode" text, "18-24" numeric, "25-34" numeric,"35-44" numeric, "45-54" numeric, "55-64" numeric, "65-74" numeric, "75-84" numeric, "85-94" numeric, "95 AND OVER" numeric);
```

Comment: [Why still Postgres 9.0? Consider upgrading.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: What are the benefits of crosstab in 9.1 and upwards? We are currently considering upgrading to a later version.

Comment: The tablefunc module has not changed much but Postgres 9.0 is just too old. It is reaching EOL right now. Follow the link.

Comment: Thanks, just looked into it and will be upgrading to 9.4.4. as soon as time permits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table definition says

```
...
ageband character(12),
...
```

which means the values in there look like `'18-24       '` instead of `'18-24'`.  This way, the items from the `VALUES` list do not match the values in the table, therefore you get an empty table as result.

If you change the column type to a bit more senseful `text` (which trims the values, too, as Erwin points it out):

```
ALTER TABLE activities_in_localities_asc ALTER COLUMN ageband TYPE text;
```

you will get your desired results.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. If say I changed the column type to character varying would this of worked without the trim? I want to now add a column at the end called 'total_count' which would contain a sum of the columns to create a new column. I have tried many variations to try and get this to work to no avail.
More importantly than this though, I want to create this table spatially by using an 'INNER JOIN' or something like that to enable me to view the data more intelligently.
I know that I could create the table and then take do a separate SQL query to do this, but strive for perfection.

Comment: A cast from `char(n)` to `text` or `varchar` does not conserve blanks, so the `UPDATE` (with `trim()`) is not necessary.

Comment: and in relation to the other part, can this be done?

Comment: @danielfranklin: Please start a new question for the new question. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter interesting, didn't notice this so far.  I've possibly never created a `char(x)` column yet that was mistyped :)

Comment: @dezso: [It's probably best, not to use `char(n)`. Ever.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)