# Add column with a sum total to crosstab() query in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, cte, postgresql-9.0, pivot

Following on from my previous question:

[Creating crosstab() pivot table in PostgreSQL 9.0](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114428/creating-crosstab-pivot-table-in-postgresql-9-0)

I managed to create a pivot table for `ageband` using the `crosstab()` function. I can use this to either create a view or table of the base geometry-less table.

However, this still isn't much use as I need to link it to the `gazetteers_and_addresses.unit_postcode` table in order to assign geometries for further analysis.

I will attach the table structure for both tables and the original code that worked to create my crosstab.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW adult_social_care.vw_ageband AS (
    SELECT * FROM crosstab(
        'SELECT postcode_nospace_, ageband, count(ageband) as total_count
         FROM adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc
         GROUP BY postcode_nospace_, ageband
         ORDER BY postcode_nospace_'

         ,$$VALUES ('18-24'::text), ('25-34'), ('35-44'), ('45-54'), ('55-64'), ('65-74'), ('75-84'), ('85-94'), ('95 AND OVER')$$)
    AS ct("postcode" text, "18-24" numeric, "25-34" numeric,"35-44" numeric, "45-54" numeric, "55-64" numeric, "65-74" numeric, "75-84" numeric, "85-94" numeric, "95 AND OVER" numeric));
```

Table defintions:

`activities_in_localities_asc`:

```
CREATE TABLE adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc (
  ogc_fid integer NOT NULL,
  sort numeric(5,0),
  ageband character(12),
  postcode_nospace_ character(8),
  wkb_geometry geometry,
  CONSTRAINT activities_in_localities_asc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ogc_fid)
);
```

`unit_postcode`:

```
CREATE TABLE gazetteers_and_addresses.unit_postcode (
  oogc_fid serial NOT NULL,
  pc_area character(10),
  postcode_nospaces text,
  wkb_geometry geometry
);
```

If possible too, assign another field at the end which states a sum of all the fields to give a `total_count`.

If this can be done then I can create dynamic views on different factors using one geometry-less table and `unit_postcode`.

Comment: So do you have your answer here?

Answer (score 5):

### Proper crosstab query

First of all, the presented query would not work while you still have `char(n)` in your table definition - [like we discussed under your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114428/3684). You would need to convert to [`text` or `varchar`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) first.

This works with your current table definition:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT postcode_nospace_::text, ageband::text, count(ageband) AS ct
    FROM   adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1'

   ,$$VALUES ('18-24'::text), ('25-34'), ('35-44'), ('45-54'), ('55-64')
           , ('65-74'), ('75-84'), ('85-94'), ('95 AND OVER')$$
   )
AS t("postcode" text
   , "18-24" bigint, "25-34" bigint,"35-44" bigint, "45-54" bigint, "55-64" bigint
   , "65-74" bigint, "75-84" bigint, "85-94" bigint, "95 AND OVER" bigint);
```

I am also using `bigint` instead of `numeric` to save another unnecessary type conversion (`count()` returns `bigint`).

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

#### Better table definition

But better `ALTER` the data type in your table to `text` like @dezso suggested. Or, if you want to keep the length limit, add a `CHECK` constraint or use `varchar(n)`. [Never use `char(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221).

```
ALTER TABLE activities_in_localities_asc
   ALTER COLUMN ageband TYPE varchar(12)
 , ALTER COLUMN postcode_nospace_ TYPE varchar(8);

 ALTER TABLE gazetteers_and_addresses.unit_postcode
   ALTER COLUMN pc_area TYPE varchar(10);
```

Then you don't need to cast original column values any more:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT postcode_nospace_, ageband, count(ageband)
    ...
```

Ideally, though, `ageband` should be an [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html) or (my preference) an ID referencing a lookup table, not plain, error-prone `text` ... key word: *normalization*.

### Add total count

Building on your table, but with `text` or `varchar()` columns.

Wrap your original query into a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) and call the the result twice in a `UNION` query - the 2nd call adds totals per postcode:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  $$WITH cte AS (
      SELECT postcode_nospace_, ageband, count(ageband) AS ct
      FROM   adult_social_care.activities_in_localities_asc  
      GROUP  BY 1, 2
      )
   TABLE  cte  -- original results
   UNION ALL   -- add total per postcode
   SELECT postcode_nospace_, 'total' AS ageband, sum(ct) AS ct
   FROM   cte
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 1$$  -- dollar-quotes to include single quotes easily

   ,$$VALUES ('18-24'::text), ('25-34'), ('35-44'), ('45-54'), ('55-64')
           , ('65-74'), ('75-84'), ('85-94'), ('95 AND OVER'), ('total')$$
   )
AS t("postcode" text
   , "18-24" bigint, "25-34" bigint,"35-44" bigint, "45-54" bigint, "55-64" bigint
   , "65-74" bigint, "75-84" bigint, "85-94" bigint, "95 AND OVER" bigint, "total" bigint);
```

About the `TABLE` command:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860)

Related CTE examples:

- [Combine results of two queries, where the second relies on the first](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94661/combine-results-of-two-queries-where-the-second-relies-on-the-first/94673#94673)
- [Get n grouped categories and sum others into one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30598887/939860)