# Converting rows to columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pivot

I have data like following:

```
    created_at       |    status    
---------------------+-------------
 2016-04-05 1:27:15  | info
 2016-04-05 3:27:15  | info
 2016-04-05 5:27:15  | warn
 2016-04-05 10:27:15 | info
 2016-04-05 11:27:15 | warn
```

With this data, I want to convert like as follows:

```
 status  | 2016-04-05 1:00:00 | 2016-04-05 4:00:00 | 2016-04-05 8:00:00 | 2016-04-05 12:00:00
---------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------
 info    | 1                  | 1                  | 0                  | 1
 warn    | 0                  | 0                  | 1                  | 1
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: `1:00, 4:00, 8:00, 12:00` ...? There is no obvious pattern behind your chosen hours. And no consistent way of counting, either. `1:27` -> `1:00`, but `5:27` -> `8:00`? Please fix your question to make sense, explain your case and put a minimum of effort into it. "psql" is the PostgreSQL interactive terminal and *not* an abbreviation for Postgres, btw.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter doesn't matter - I've answered. Essentially, the timeslots can be arbitrary - using code like this "CASE WHEN created_at <  ''2016-04-05 02:00'' THEN 1 WHEN created_at >= ''2016-04-05 02:00'' AND created_at < ''2016-04-05 04:00'' THEN 2. Suggesting to OP  2 hour tranches, but it's up to them. I have 1 question to truly polish my answer though, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905) you say "second parameter can be any query that returns one row per attribute" - what happens if no such row exists? See my sample data!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `2016-04-05 0:27:15` instead of <strike>`2016-04-05 1:27:15`</strike> in the underlying table, the question would make more sense to me:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (created_at timestamp, status text);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('2016-04-05 00:27:15', 'info')
, ('2016-04-05 03:27:15', 'info')
, ('2016-04-05 05:27:15', 'warn')
, ('2016-04-05 10:27:15', 'info')
, ('2016-04-05 11:27:15', 'warn');
```

The logic would be to count events that happened up to and *excluding* the next bound. This fits the often overlooked function [**`width_bucket()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) perfectly. To be precise, it requires the variant with *arbitrary* bounds (since there is no regular pattern in the OP's bounds) introduced with Postgres **9.5**. Explanation straight from the manual:

> ```
> width_bucket(operand anyelement, thresholds anyarray)
> ```
>
> return the bucket number to which `operand` would be assigned given an
>   array listing the lower bounds of the buckets; returns `0` for an input
>   less than the first lower bound; the `thresholds` array **must be sorted**,
>   smallest first, or unexpected results will be obtained

For *regular* buckets you can use another variant that's [available in Postgres 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) as well.
Combine it with `crosstab()` re-using the same bounds as column names (the rest of the query works with Postgres 9.1):

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
 $$SELECT status
        , width_bucket(created_at, '{2016-04-05 01:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 04:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 08:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 12:00}'::timestamp[])
        , count(*)::int
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  created_at < '2016-04-05 12:00'  -- exclude later rows
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
, 'SELECT generate_series(0,3)'
   ) AS t(status text, "2016-04-05 01:00" int
                     , "2016-04-05 04:00" int
                     , "2016-04-05 08:00" int
                     , "2016-04-05 12:00" int);
```

Result:

```
 status | 2016-04-05 01:00 | 2016-04-05 04:00 | 2016-04-05 08:00 | 2016-04-05 12:00
--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
 info   |                1 |                1 |                  |  1
 warn   |                  |                  |                1 |  1
```

The second crosstab parameter (`'SELECT generate_series(0,3)'`) is a query string when executed returning *one row* for every target column. Every value not found on either side - not in the raw data or not generated by the 2nd parameter - is *simply ignored*.

Basics for `crosstab()`:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

#### Replace NULL with 0

If you need `0` instead of `NULL` in the result, fix with `COALESCE()`, but that's merely a cosmetic problem:

```
SELECT status
     , COALESCE(t0, 0) AS "2016-04-05 01:00"
     , COALESCE(t1, 0) AS "2016-04-05 04:00"
     , COALESCE(t2, 0) AS "2016-04-05 08:00"
     , COALESCE(t3, 0) AS "2016-04-05 12:00"
FROM   crosstab(
 $$SELECT status
        , width_bucket(created_at, '{2016-04-05 01:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 04:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 08:00
                                   , 2016-04-05 12:00}'::timestamp[])
        , count(*)::int
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  created_at < '2016-04-05 12:00'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
, 'SELECT generate_series(0,3)'
   ) AS t(status text, t0 int, t1 int, t2 int, t3 int);
```

Result:

```
 status | 2016-04-05 01:00 | 2016-04-05 04:00 | 2016-04-05 08:00 | 2016-04-05 12:00
--------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
 info   |                1 |                1 |                0 |  1
 warn   |                0 |                0 |                1 |  1
```

#### Adding totals

To add totals per `status` use the new [**`GROUPING SETS`** in Postgres 9.5+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

```
SELECT status
     , COALESCE(t0, 0) AS "2016-04-05 01:00"
     , COALESCE(t1, 0) AS "2016-04-05 04:00"
     , COALESCE(t2, 0) AS "2016-04-05 08:00"
     , COALESCE(t3, 0) AS "2016-04-05 12:00"
     , COALESCE(t4, 0) AS total
FROM   crosstab(
 $$SELECT status, COALESCE(slot, -1), ct  -- special slot for totals
   FROM  (
      SELECT status
           , width_bucket(created_at, '{2016-04-05 01:00
                                      , 2016-04-05 04:00
                                      , 2016-04-05 08:00
                                      , 2016-04-05 12:00}'::timestamp[]) AS slot
           , count(*)::int AS ct
      FROM   tbl
      WHERE  created_at < '2016-04-05 12:00'
      GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ((1, 2), 1)  -- add totals per status
      ORDER  BY 1, 2
      ) sub$$
 , 'VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (-1)'  -- switched to VALUES for more sophisticated series
   ) AS t(status text, t0 int, t1 int, t2 int, t3 int, t4 int);
```

Result like above, plus:

```
...  | total
... -+-------
...  |     3
...  |     2
```

Note that `total` includes all rows not excluded *before* aggregation, even if filtered by `crosstab()`.

*This is in reply to [@Vérace's request in the comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134874/converting-rows-in-to-columns-in-psql?noredirect=1#comment253393_134874) rather than to the unclear question.*

Comment: Very nice - +1 (as usual!). Just one small question - what is the 'VALUES(0)...(-1)' expression doing? Especially the (-1) bit - I've got my head around everything else.

Comment: @Vérace: `-1` is just the arbitrary value I assign to the "total" slot with `COALESCE(slot, -1)`. ( I didn't add column aliases as those are ignored by `crosstab()` anyway.) The totals are added *last* by `GROUPING SETS` with `NULL` as `slot` value. Try the inner `SELECT` first to see ...

Answer (score 5):

To answer this, I did the following. (I found the following three threads helpful - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870515/postgresql-cross-tab-with-three-columns-with-values-summed-from-one-column), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114474/add-column-with-a-sum-total-to-crosstab-query-in-postgresql-9-0) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905). I also found the documentation on `generate_series` and `CROSSTAB` [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tablefunc.html) respectively to be useful). This **should** work on 9.1 - not tested, but the documentation indicates that no post-9.1 stuff is being used.

Created a table:

```
ntest=# create table pv_tab(created_at timestamp, status varchar(10));
```

and populated it.

```
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 01:27:15', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 03:27:15', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 05:27:15', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:27:15', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 11:27:15', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 00:27:15', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 00:24:15', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 00:24:13', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 00:24:13', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 01:24:13', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 01:24:13', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 01:12:13', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 01:12:22', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 02:05:45', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 02:34:45', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:34:45', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:35:45', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:36:45', 'warn');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:36:45', 'info');
INSERT INTO pv_tab VALUES('2016-04-05 10:36:34', 'info');
(20 rows)
```

The (correct) result of my query is:

```
stat        slot1   slot2   slot3   slot4  slot5  slot6   Total
----        -----   -----   -----   -----  -----  -----   -----
info            6       2       0       3      0      0      11
warn            3       1       1       4      0      0       9
```

The working query is:

```
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB
(
'
WITH time_slots AS
(
  SELECT
    status,
    CASE

      -- Here I put the "created_at" values into "buckets" - it would
      -- not be desirable to have too many of these buckets - certainly
      -- any more than 12 would make the `SQL` and result unwieldy!

      -- I recommend that you create 2hr slots - 00:00 - 02:00, &c.
      -- This `CTE` splits the times into the various slots sample slots
      -- 1-4 - you can, of course, have more but it makes the `SQL` and 
      -- the answer more messy. Here, I;ve deliberately only used 4
      -- out of 6 in order to illustrate dealing with sparse data in 
      -- the result. (I used the OP;s initial slots - easy to change).

      WHEN created_at <  ''2016-04-05 02:00'' THEN 1
      WHEN created_at >= ''2016-04-05 02:00'' AND created_at < ''2016-04-05 04:00'' THEN 2
      WHEN created_at >= ''2016-04-05 04:00'' AND created_at < ''2016-04-05 08:00'' THEN 3
      WHEN created_at >= ''2016-04-05 08:00'' AND created_at < ''2016-04-05 12:00'' THEN 4
    END AS time_slot,
    COUNT(status) AS stat_count
  FROM pv_tab
  GROUP BY status, time_slot
  ORDER BY status, time_slot
),
statuae AS
  -- Get all statuses. Hardly necessary when there are only two, but
  -- could be an issue later if more values are required ("unknown"..  &c.).
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS stati
  FROM pv_tab
),
all_slots (slots) AS
  -- This `CTE` is necessary to perform a cross-join between statuses 
  -- and slots. This is because the `CROSSTAB` table function doesn;t 
  -- appear to play well with `NULL`s - see my question to Erwin
  -- Brandstetter in comments.
(
  SELECT generate_series(1, 6) -- six (should be) 2 hour slots. In any case, it is arbitrary!
),
stat_slots AS
  -- Here the statuses slots are cross-joined - i.e. all slots with all statuses.
(
  SELECT statuae.stati, all_slots.slots
  FROM statuae, all_slots
),
individual_stati AS
  -- `Left-join` the complete status/slot table with the actual slots in
  -- the sample table. NULL counts are `COALESCE`ed into 0 - necessary, otherwise
  -- `NULL`s "back up" the result and leaves blanks in the right-most 
  -- columns - and the totals appear in what should be slots. 
(
  SELECT ss.stati AS status, ss.slots AS time_slot, COALESCE(ts.stat_count, 0) AS counts
  FROM stat_slots ss
  LEFT JOIN time_slots ts
  ON ss.stati = ts.status AND ss.slots = ts.time_slot
  ORDER BY 1, 2
),
total_stati AS
  -- This is just pure showing off :-). I;m using this `CTE` to add
  -- a totals field to the query. Not asked for by the OP - can be
  -- ripped out! I got the idea for this from the 3rd link (top of post).
(
  SELECT status, 7 AS time_slot, count(status) AS counts -- 7 - an exta slot for totals
  FROM pv_tab
  GROUP BY status
)
-- Final query bringing it all together - nice, simple and elegant. :-)
SELECT status, time_slot, counts FROM individual_stati
UNION
SELECT status, time_slot, counts FROM total_stati
ORDER BY 1, 2
'
) AS My_Tab("stat" varchar(10), "slot1" bigint, "slot2" bigint, "slot3" bigint, "slot4" bigint, "slot5" bigint, "slot6" bigint, "Total" bigint);
```

Comment: `NULL counts are COALESCEed into 0 - necessary, otherwise
 NULLs "back up" the result and leaves blanks in the right-most columns` - that's what the **2nd parameter** to `crosstab()` is for, explained in detail in [my answer you referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)