# How to have row values as column headers with the associated values in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

This is hard to explain but I'll do my best. So to make it simple, I have 3 tables with the following format:

Creator table

```
id | name
 1 | jack
 2 | doge
 3 | cardano
```

roads

```
id | creator_id | length
 1 |     1      |   3
 2 |     1      |   2
 3 |     3      |   9
 4 |     1      |   3
```

Blocks

```
id | creator_id | length
 1 |    1       |   4
 2 |    1       |   4
 3 |    3       |   5
 4 |    1       |   3
```

I can't seem to pick out the rows into columns, otherwise I would be posting here but the query I use to bring the data together is:

```
select name, layer, sum(length)
from ( SELect a.name, 'road routes'::text as layer, length
       from creator a
       LEFT JOIN road_routes b on a.id = b.creator
       where a.id in (73, 35, 33, 31)
       group by a.name, layer, length
     union
       SELECT a.name, 'block routes'::text as layer, length
       from creator a
       LEFT JOIN block_route b on a.id = b.route_creator
       where a.id in (73, 35, 33, 31)
       group by a.name, layer, length) x
group by layer, name
```

The expected result and what I need is a table with the following output:

```
type   | jack | doge | cardano | total
roads  | 8    | 0    | 9       | 17
blocks | 11   | 0    | 5       | 16
```

How to sort the data like this?

Comment: You need to create tablefunc
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html
Follow this tutorial 
http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function

Comment: crosstab (pivot) solutions requires a well known number of columns, otherwise you should build it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this [good answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114531/110455) of [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter)

But keep in mind that your solution requires a dynamic query because I'm sure that `creator` table has different records from these you has posted here.

> ```
> create table creator (id int primary key, name text);
> insert into creator values (1, 'jack'),(2, 'doge'),(3, 'cardano');
> create table roads(id int primary key, creator_id int references creator(id), length int);
> insert into roads values (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2), (3, 3, 9), (4, 1, 3);
> create table blocks(id int primary key, creator_id int references creator(id), length int);
> insert into blocks values (1, 1, 4), (2, 1, 4), (3, 3, 5), (4, 1, 3);
> ```

I've used a view to get results for `roads` and `blocks`.

> ```
> create view my_view 
> as
> select 'roads' as subject, c.name,
>        coalesce((select sum(length) from roads where creator_id = c.id), 0)::int as length
> from   creator c
> union all
> select 'blocks' as subject, c.name,
>        coalesce((select sum(length) from blocks where creator_id = c.id), 0)::int as length
> from   creator c;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from 
> crosstab 
> (
>   $$select subject, name, length 
>     from my_view
>     union all
>     select subject, 'total'::text as name, coalesce(sum(length),0)::bigint as length
>     from my_view
>     group by subject
>     order by 1,2$$
> )
> as t ("subject" text, "cardano" bigint, "doge" bigint, "jack" bigint, "total" bigint)
> ```
>
> ```
> subject | cardano | doge | jack | total
> :------ | ------: | ---: | ---: | ----:
> blocks  |       5 |    0 |   11 |    16
> roads   |       9 |    0 |    8 |    17
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1c08cacb5ea2e4c6a5385191586f085e)*

Comment: The fiddle is exactly what I need, thanks!

You're right, there are a lot more creators but for this task I only need 4 creators listed plus the total sum

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.